# Why does 'result' not need to be mut?

Tags: rust

I'm just about to learn rust with the rust book. What I understood is, that I can't assign to variables, that aren't declared mut. So I'm wondering, why this code works:

```
extern crate num_bigint;
use num_bigint::BigUint;

fn main() {
    let n = 10_000;
    println!("{}! = {};", n, factorial_recursive(n));
}

fn factorial_recursive(n: usize) -> BigUint {
    let result: BigUint;
    if n == 0 { result = BigUint::new(vec![1]); }
    else { result = factorial_recursive(n-1) * n; }
    result
}
```

In the beginning, I had declared result mut, but I got a compiler warning, that mut isn't necessary. So I removed it, and was surprised, that it still works.
Why is that so?

PS: I know, that I could return directly from the if/else branches. I had this in the beginning, but wanted to print out result, before returning, so I changed to this and got the compiler warning about mut not necessary. Now I want to understand this.

Comment: Hi :) I marked your question as duplicate. If the linked answers don't help you, please [edit] your question to explain why your question is different than the one I linked. Thanks and have fun in continuing your Rust journey!

Comment: Oh, thx. That exactly answers my question. Nice rust feature.

Comment: Note that your whole function can be written like this: `if n == 0 { 1_u32.into() } else { factorial_recursive(n - 1) * n }`. No need of `result`.